# Owl Carousel 2 mousewheel slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel-2

Is there an option to scroll only one of the owl-carousel sliders on mousewheel?
When i click the prev or next btn it's slides only the current carousel but on mousewheel slides all!

**HTML**

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
   <div class="item">
      item
   </div>
   <div class="item">
      item
   </div>
   <div class="item">
      item
   </div> 
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
   loop: true,
   margin: 30,
   nav: true, 
   responsiveClass: true,
   responsive: {
      0: {
         items: 1 
      },
      600: {
         items: 2 
      },
      1000: {
         items: 3
      }
   }
});
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function(e) {
   if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      owl.trigger('next.owl');
   } else {
      owl.trigger('prev.owl');
   }
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shokwave/ghqpkmes/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, In your code `owl = $('.owl-carousel')` is grabbing all the nodes with class `owl-carousel`. Thus when `mousewheel` event happens, causes scrolling of all the slides. So you need to give reference to the currently focused slider and trigger events only of that slider. Hope this fixes your issue. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunal12422/hjwrduxy/1/)

Comment: Owl was not working in Fiddle because of you have not attached jquery `Mousewheel` file.